# Allow accessibility screen reader to read a number string one-by-one as digits using semantics [flutter]

Tags: flutter, dart, accessibility, screen-readers

I'm using `Semantics` to adapt my app for accessibility and want to read a phone number (like: `Text("950874123")`) one to one instead "million, thousand...". Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I see this was asked a while back, but I ran into the same problem.  I'm adding my solution here to help out the next guy.

I got the solution with the help of this page:
https://medium.com/theotherdev-s/mastering-flutter-semantics-672440bc8bc8

Basically, my solution is to use the Semantics label (that I can control) and use ExcludeSemantics to exclude the text that I'm reading.  In the label, I divide everything up into an array that I convert into a string.  This makes the screen reader see everything as individual numbers.

Here's an example

```
Semantics(
   label: numberString.split("").toString(),
      child: ExcludeSemantics(
         excluding: true,
            child: Text(numberString),          
             )
 )
```

*Edit:
After playing around more with the code, I realized that the Text field has a property called "semanticsLabel" where you can do the same thing.  I left the above example since it can be used for other widget types, not just Text()

This is what the code would look like:

```
Semantics(
   child: Text(
      viewModel.confirmationId,
      semanticsLabel:numberString.split("").toString(),
    )
)
```

(additionally, the parent 'Semantics' widget probably isn't needed.  The label will work directly with the Text widget)

Comment: Does that effectively make the phone number look like "9 5 0 8 7 4 1 2 3"?  If so, keep in mind that Braille users will read the phone number with all those embedded spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue when displaying the last 4 digits of a credit card. My solution:

```
TextSpan(
    text: ' ending in ${paymentMethod.last4}',
    semanticsLabel: 'ending in ${(paymentMethod.last4 ?? '').characters.join(',').toString()}',
    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge,
),
```